# How to debug "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0" in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm trying to make Kim Asendorf's pixel sorting code work with input from a webcam in processing.

I get the error: "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0". Any ideas of how I can fix this?

```
//BLACK
int getFirstNotBlackY(int _x, int _y) {
int x = _x;
int y = _y;
color c;
if (y < height) {
while ( (c = cam.pixels[x + y * cam.width]) < blackValue) {
  y++;
  if (y >= height) return -1;
}




import processing.video.*;

Capture cam; 

String[] cameras = Capture.list();

int mode = 0;

//MODE:
//0 -> black
//1 -> bright
//2 -> white
//b(16777216)


int loops = 1;

int blackValue = -10000000;
int brigthnessValue = 60;
int whiteValue = -6000000;

int row = 0;
int column =

boolean saved = false;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);

  import processing.video.*;

  String[] cameras = Capture.list();

  import processing.video.*;

  if (cameras.length == 0) {
    println("There are no cameras available for capture.");
    exit();
  } else {
    println("Available cameras:");
    for (int i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
      println(cameras[i]);
    }

    // The camera can be initialized directly using an 
    // element from the array returned by list():
    cam = new Capture(this, cameras[0]);
    cam.start();
  }
 }
```

I've added the code I'm using to initialize the webcam.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you provide a [mcve]. But it looks like your camera is not connected. Have you done any debugging to check this? Try using `println()` statements to test things out.

Comment: Hi @KevinWorkman, thanks for taking the time to reply. I'm not sure if I could make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. The original Kim Asendorf code is quite long, and i've semi trial-and-error'd integrating the  capture cam code. Is there anyway I could show my code?? I've include println(); & in the console its showing different available cameras

Comment: From the error, it looks like `cam.pixels[]` is empty. It's going to be hard to debug since it requires hardware (the camera), but we at least need to see how you're initializing the `cam` variable. If I were you, I'd start smaller. Can you just get a basic stream working first?

Comment: the 'cam.pixels[]' originally read 'img.pixels[]' as the code originally inputs from an image file and I've tweaked it for a webcam, if that helps. I can get the webcam to work, but if I to merge it with any or all of the Asendorf code it produces errors. I'll edit my original post to include how I'm initializing the 'cam' variable, thanks

Comment: why does your coded start with an `if` with an opening `{` without a closing `}`?  It's worth running through the code you posted, and first formatting it properly, and make sure it's properly set up first.

Comment: This code doesn't make a lot of sense. How does it even compile? Why do you have random import statements? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Perhaps this is simply an artifact of how you've tried to paste in portions of the program, but... you're declaring `Capture cam;` after you attempt to use it in `getFirstNotBlackY`.  You'll need to declare it first, even though you're initializing it in `setup()`.